# Can we generate new page in Next js dynamically without create a new page file

Tags: next.js, server-side-rendering, headless-cms, static-site-generation

I want to pull everything from an headless CMS, this is possible in gatsby to create new pages, So my question is that is it possible to create new pages in Next js without creating a new page file manually.

Comment: It depends, what exactly do you mean by _"create new pages in Next js"_? Do you mean adding a new page to an existing dynamic route? Or do you mean adding a branding new, non-existing route altogether? Can you provide more details of your current `pages` folder structure and how/where you want to add that new page?